# intel-virtual-output command for Saucy 13.10 with dual monitor setup and hybrid graphic

Tags: 13.10, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics, gpu-driver

I want to configure/use a second display on my Thinkpad W530 with Intel/Nvidia hybrid graphics. Bumblebee from Ubuntu ppa is installed.

After hours on searching the web, i found a solution which uses a patched Intel graphics driver with virtual screen and a little tool called screenclone. ([Optimal Ubuntu Graphics Setup for Thinkpads](http://sagark.org/optimal-ubuntu-graphics-setup-for-thinkpads/))

But this solution isn't for 13.10 and i found out that the xserver-xorg-video-intel driver 2.99 has a tool for supporting virtual screens "intel-virtual-output".

The Tool "intel-virtual-output" isn't build & distribute at this time.([Build and distribute intel-virtual-output](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1247528) )

I have tried to build and install the driver from source:

```
apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-video-intel
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-intel
cd xf86-video-intel
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
make && sudo make install
```

But the version of package xserver-xorg-video-intel isn't change and the tool intel-virtual-output isn't available in terminal.

The package on the xorg-edgers ppa also doesn't include the tool for virtual screens.

How can I install the tool "intel-virtual-output"?

Thanks in advance and excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps:

**Intel-virtual-output tool**

First, you will need latest xf86-video-intel driver installed (2.99). Ubuntu 13.10 comes with it, so you don’t need to update driver in that case. However, what made all of this possible is the latest release of intel-virtual-output tool, which comes bundled with xf86-video-intel driver source. But, ubuntu’s package does not bundle it, and we need to compile it from source. One MAJOR thing to note here is: DO NOT compile it from ubuntu’s deb-src package. That package is old, and current release has some major fixes for the tool that we will actually need in order to have everything working properly. So lets do it:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev git git 
clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-intel 
cd xf86-video-intel  
./autogen.sh  
cd tools 
make  
sudo cp intel-virtual-output /usr/bin/  
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/intel-virtual-output
```

Taken from here: http://www.unixreich.com/blog/2013/linux-nvidia-optimus-on-thinkpad-w520w530-with-external-monitor-finally-solved/

Comment: After compiling with make, it seems there is no file named intel-virtual-output. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/676317/problem-building-intel-virtual-output

Answer (score 3):

I managed to build the `intel-virtual-output` tool with following commands:

```
# get all official build dependencies
sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-video-intel

# make sure all undocumented dependecies are installed as well
for l in xinerama xrandr xdamage xfixes xcursor xtst xrender xext x11 pixman-1 ; do echo lib$l-dev ; done | xargs -n99 sudo apt-get -y install

cd ~ # or wherever you want

# get the source
apt-get source xserver-xorg-video-intel
cd xserver-xorg-video-intel

# tell dpkg-buildpackage to include the binary into the package
echo "usr/bin/intel-virtual-output" >> debian/xserver-xorg-video-intel.install

# build the package
dpkg-buildpackage -b

# check the ouput
ls -l ./debian/tmp/usr/bin/intel-virtual-output # this is your binary
```

Install it by just coping your bin to `/usr/local/bin` or by installing the `deb` package you just build.

Comment: Thanks, two last command from [this guide](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1247528/comments/4) were also helpful for me.