# Problem building intel-virtual-output

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, thinkpad, bumblebee

Following [this guide](http://www.unixreich.com/blog/2013/linux-nvidia-optimus-on-thinkpad-w520w530-with-external-monitor-finally-solved/) and many others I'm trying to getting my ThinkPad w520 with ubuntu gnome 14.04.3 (64bit) work with bumblebee. I have however a strange problem, when I try to build the intel-virtual-output from the xf86-video-intel I don't get the binary intel-virtual-output in the folder tools.

Do someone know why?

The output of `./autogen.sh` is:

```
david@david-ubuntu:~/src/xf86-video-intel$ ./autogen.sh autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS} -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, `.'.
libtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
libtoolize: copying file `m4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --no-force
configure.ac:44: installing './compile'
configure.ac:44: installing './config.guess'
configure.ac:44: installing './config.sub'
configure.ac:35: installing './install-sh'
configure.ac:35: installing './missing'
benchmarks/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking whether __clang__ is declared... no
checking whether __INTEL_COMPILER is declared... no
checking whether __SUNPRO_C is declared... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Werror=unknown-warning-option... no
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Werror=unused-command-line-argument... no
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wall... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wpointer-arith... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wmissing-declarations... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wformat=2... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wstrict-prototypes... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wmissing-prototypes... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wnested-externs... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wbad-function-cast... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wold-style-definition... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wdeclaration-after-statement... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wunused... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wuninitialized... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wshadow... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wcast-qual... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wmissing-noreturn... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wmissing-format-attribute... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wredundant-decls... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=implicit... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=nonnull... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=init-self... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=main... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=missing-braces... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=sequence-point... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=return-type... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=trigraphs... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=array-bounds... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=write-strings... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=address... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-pedantic... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Werror=attributes... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wno-cast-qual... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wno-redundant-decls... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports-Wno-maybe-uninitialized... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc -std=gnu99... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc -std=gnu99 object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc -std=gnu99 linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for strlcpy... no
checking for strlcat... no
checking for strndup... yes
checking for native atomic primitives... Intel
checking for UDEV... no
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking for X11... no
X11_CLFAGS= X11_LIBS=
checking sys/ipc.h usability... yes
checking sys/ipc.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ipc.h... yes
checking for sys/ipc.h... (cached) yes
checking for X11/extensions/XShm.h... yes
checking for X11/extensions/shmproto.h... yes
checking for X11/extensions/shmstr.h... yes
checking whether shmctl IPC_RMID allows subsequent attaches... yes
checking for X11_DRI3... no
checking for IVO_EXTRA... yes
checking for X11/extensions/Xinerama.h... yes
checking for IVO_EXTRA... yes
checking for IVO... no
checking sys/timerfd.h usability... yes
checking sys/timerfd.h presence... yes
checking for sys/timerfd.h... yes
checking for TOOL_CURSOR... yes
checking whether to build additional tools... no
checking if RANDR is defined... yes
checking if RENDER is defined... yes
checking if DPMSExtension is defined... yes
checking for DRM... yes
checking for PCIACCESS... yes
checking dev/wscons/wsconsio.h usability... no
checking dev/wscons/wsconsio.h presence... no
checking for dev/wscons/wsconsio.h... no
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking whether sys/types.h defines makedev... yes
checking sys/sysinfo.h usability... yes
checking sys/sysinfo.h presence... yes
checking for sys/sysinfo.h... yes
checking for struct sysinfo.totalram... yes
checking for DRMINTEL... yes
checking for XORG... yes
checking vgaHW.h usability... yes
checking vgaHW.h presence... yes
checking for vgaHW.h... yes
checking xaa.h usability... no
checking xaa.h presence... no
checking for xaa.h... no
checking whether to include XAA support... no
checking for dgaproc.h... yes
checking whether to include DGA support... yes
checking if XF86DRI is defined... yes
checking for DRI1... yes
checking for dri.h... yes
checking for sarea.h... yes
checking for dristruct.h... yes
checking whether to include DRI1 support... auto
checking for DRI2... yes
checking for dri2.h... yes
checking if DRI3 is defined... yes
checking for DRI3... yes
checking whether DRI3 is declared... yes
checking for misyncstr.h... yes
checking for misyncshm.h... yes
checking whether to include DRI2 support... auto
checking whether to include DRI3 support... auto
checking default DRI support... 
checking X11/extensions/dpmsconst.h usability... yes
checking X11/extensions/dpmsconst.h presence... yes
checking for X11/extensions/dpmsconst.h... yes
checking if PRESENT is defined... yes
checking for PRESENT... yes
checking for present.h... yes
checking whether to include PRESENT support... yes
checking whether to include UXA support... yes
checking whether to include SNA support... auto
checking for XVMCLIB... no
checking whether to include XvMC support... no
checking which acceleration method to use by default... sna
checking for library containing clock_gettime... none required
checking for getline... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating libobj/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/legacy/Makefile
config.status: creating src/legacy/i810/Makefile
config.status: creating src/legacy/i810/xvmc/Makefile
config.status: creating src/render_program/Makefile
config.status: creating src/sna/Makefile
config.status: creating src/sna/brw/Makefile
config.status: creating src/sna/fb/Makefile
config.status: creating src/uxa/Makefile
config.status: creating xvmc/Makefile
config.status: creating xvmc/shader/Makefile
config.status: creating xvmc/shader/mc/Makefile
config.status: creating xvmc/shader/vld/Makefile
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating benchmarks/Makefile
config.status: creating tools/Makefile
config.status: creating tools/org.x.xf86-video-intel.backlight-helper.policy
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands


xf86-video-intel
Open-source X.org graphics driver for Intel graphics
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/

What is xf86-video-intel
------------------------
The xf86-video-intel module is an open-source 2D graphics driver for
the X Window System as implemented by X.org. It supports a variety of
Intel graphics chipsets including:

    i810/i810e/i810-dc100,i815,
    i830M,845G,852GM,855GM,865G,
    915G/GM,945G/GM/GME,946GZ
    G/GM/GME/Q965,
    G/Q33,G/Q35,G41,G/Q43,G/GM/Q45
    PineView-M (Atom N400 series)
    PineView-D (Atom D400/D500 series)
    Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000,
    Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100/6100, and
    Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200/6200/P6300.

Where to get more information about the driver
----------------------------------------------
The primary source of information about this and other open-source
drivers for Intel graphics is:

    https://01.org/linuxgraphics/

Documentation specific to the xf86-video-intel driver including
possible configuration options for the xorg.conf file can be found in
the intel(4) manual page. After installing the driver this
documentation can be read with the following command:

    man intel

Mailing list for communication with users and developers of
xf86-video-intel:

    intel-gfx@lists.freedesktop.org

    Note: Subscription is required before posting, but anyone is
    free to subscribe. See instructions (and archives) here:

    http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/intel-gfx

To report bugs encountered with the driver, see:

    https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/how-report-bugs

To see bugs that are targeted to be fixed in the next release:

    https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=intel-2d-release

xf86-video-intel 2.99.917 will be compiled with:
  Xorg Video ABI version: 15.0 (xorg-server-1.15.1)
  pixman version: pixman-1-0.30.2
  Acceleration backends: none *sna uxa
  Additional debugging support? none
  Support for Kernel Mode Setting? yes
  Support for legacy User Mode Setting (for i810)? yes
  Support for Direct Rendering Infrastructure: DRI1 *DRI2 DRI3 Present
  Support for Xv motion compensation (XvMC and libXvMC): no
  Support for display hotplug notifications (udev): no
  Build additional tools and utilities? xf86-video-intel-backlight-helper
```

The output of the `make` command:

```
david@david-ubuntu:~/src/xf86-video-intel/tools$ make
  CC       backlight_helper.o
  CCLD     xf86-video-intel-backlight-helper
  CC       cursor-cursor.o
  CCLD     cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

I was following the same blog and faced the exact same problem today. 
Found out from http:// github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup ...

> Check and see if you have the tool 'intel-virtual-output' installed. This is included in 'xf86-video-intel' =< v2.99, aprox date released is 22/Dec/2014

Got to https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads and search for a build older than Dec 2014. Found this this : http:// xorg.freedesktop.org/archive/individual/driver/xf86-video-intel-2.99.911.tar.gz

Open command prompt and run the following commands.

```
tar -xvf xf86-video-intel-2.99.911.tar.gz
cd xf86-video-intel-2.99.911/
./configure
make
```

You will find the "intel-virtual-output" in the tools/ folder.

Related blog : http://blog.lukeswart.net/wordpress/?p=6

Comment: Please provide the required steps in your answer. When the links break your answer will be useless.

Comment: The source you linked failed to compile: fbcopy.c: In function 'sfbCopyPlane':
fbcopy.c:222:10: error: too many arguments to function 'miHandleExposures'
   return miHandleExposures(src, dst, gc,